# Functions from/into empty set and its sets

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

The function from an empty set (which is a function called „empty function“), namely $f: \emptyset \to A$, results in $f = \{\emptyset\}$.

The function into an empty set from a non-empty set B, namely $g: B \to \emptyset$, is not a function and therefore the set $g = \emptyset$.

Is this correct?

Can there be a case where some function h is even undefined, like we know it with the division of zero, resulting in $h = undef.$ (apart from the trivial case that the function is not precisely defined, e.g. because someone had a bad hand writing)?

Comment: If $g$ does not exist, then it is not equal to the empty set, which does exist.

Comment: And $\{\varnothing\}$ is not empty, so that is not the empty function. Which is empty. So $f$ cannot equal $\{\varnothing\}$.

Comment: The empty function $f$ is not equal to $\{\emptyset\}$. The empty function IS the empty set: $f=\emptyset$

Comment: With regards to division by zero concerns... strictly speaking, those are not functions in the first place due to those division by zero errors.  The "function" $f~:~\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ given by $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is invalid since $f(0)$ is undefined.  It should not have been called a function.  What is really meant most of the time when talking about this example is to have talked about $f$ *restricted to a domain* for which the function is defined (*and usually the maximal such set*).  They really mean to be talking about the function $f~:~\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}\to \Bbb R$

Comment: Also, to emphasize... $\{\emptyset\}\neq \emptyset$.  The set on the left is of size $1$ since it has an element (*the emptyset*) in it.  The set on the right is of size $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this is what you have in mind: The **set of all functions** from the empty set to $A$, $\{f\mid f:\emptyset \to A\} = \{\emptyset\}$, because there is only one function from $\emptyset$ to $A$, the empty function $f=\emptyset$.

On the other hand, **the set of all functions** from a non-empty set $B$ to the empty set, $\{g \mid g:B \to \emptyset\} = \emptyset$, since there's no such functions.